# Where do I implement my MFC DLL functions?

Tags: c++, windows, class, dll, mfc

I have been searching google all morning and all I can't find what I'm looking for.  I'm creating a regular DLL in Visual Studio modified for MFC.  That is to say that in the project wizard, I selected

```
Win32 Project -> DLL -> MFC
```

I did **NOT** just click MFC DLL from the main list in the wizard, which is what all the tutorials online were describing.

My question is simple.  In the .cpp file, **I just need to know whether I'm supposed to implement my methods (declared in the .h file) *inside* or *outside* of the `_tmain` function.** 
Inside there is a comment that says

```
//TODO: code your applications behavior here
```

but I'm not sure if that's where my implementations go.

For reference, here is the .cpp file:

```
// testmfcdllblah.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "testmfcdllblah.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// The one and only application object

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
        if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
        {
            // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
            _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
            nRetCode = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }

    return nRetCode;
}
```

Comment: DLLs don't contain main-functions... Would be quite curious if that was different for MFC.

Comment: I'm thinking that the _tmain function here serves only to allow compatability with MFC, which would mean to implement my methods outside.  But they didn't actually say where to implement them, so I'm not quite sure...

Comment: Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2516/Creating-and-consuming-MFC-DLLs-for-Beginners) article out.

Comment: Thanks for the article but that's one of the ones I looked at that are for DLL's that are ONLY usable with MFC, mine is a regular DLL modified to work with MFC.

Comment: Then I don't get the issue...

Comment: Dll's can have a main function, just as they can define an PE32 entry point ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot implement functions/methods inside other functions your method implementation need to go outside the `_tmain` function.

The comment block you quoted can be replaced to supply an initialisation implementation of your library.

So if you are declaring a function like `SayHello` this could look like so:

`testmfcdllblah.h`:

```
// Declaration
void SayHello(void);
```

`testmfcdllblah.cpp`:

```
void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    // .. all the other stuff ..

    // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
    SayHello();

    // .. the rest of the other stuff ..
}

void SayHello()
{
    AfxMessageBox("Hello!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can't define local functions. You will never implement any function in _tmain.

When you have used the wizard to create a DLL you should add a header file that defines your interface to the DLL. And you should add a .CPP source file where you implement the function(s).

You can **call** function at that place where you find

```
// TODO: change error code to suit your needs
```

BTW: I don't know why the wizard for a Dynamic Link Library creates a main function.

Comment: Because DLL's can also define entry points ;) This can be usefull to initialize them whenever they are loaded into a process. As far as I remember MFC uses this to initialize COM (and several other resources)...